Tiktok Marketing API
I encountered an issue with my code while attempting to use the TikTok API to fetch reports similar to those generated in TikTok Ads Manager. I followed the documentation on campaign_name, ad_name, and various metrics, but I'm getting an error indicating that some metrics fields are invalid. Here's the relevant part of my code:
import requests
import json
import pandas as pd
from datetime import date

# Define the API endpoint and parameters
url = "https://business-api.tiktok.com/open_api/v1.2/reports/integrated/get/"
params = {
    "advertiser_id": " ",  # Replace with your advertiser ID
    "report_type": "BASIC",
    "start_date": "2024-06-10",  # Replace with your start date
    "end_date": date.today(),    # Replace with your end date
    "data_level": "AUCTION_ADVERTISER",
    "dimensions": json.dumps(["advertiser_id", "stat_time_day"]), # Include stat_time_day as a dimension
    "page_size": 1000,
    "metrics": json.dumps([
        "campaign_name",
        "ad_name",
        "cpc",
        "cpm",
        "impressions",
        "clicks",
        "ctr",
        "reach",
        "conversion",
        "cost_per_conversion",
        "conversion_rate",
        "conversion_rate_v2",
        "video_watched_2s",
        "video_watched_6s",
        "engaged_view",
        "engagements",
        "page_content_view_events"
    ])
}

# Define the headers, including the access token
headers = {
    "Access-Token": " "  # Replace with your access token
}

# Make the GET request
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, params=params)

# Check the status code and process the response
if response.status_code == 200:
    data = response.json()
    print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))  # Print the entire response for debugging

    # Adjust the DataFrame creation based on the actual response structure
    if "data" in data and "list" in data["data"]:
        df = pd.DataFrame(data["data"]["list"])
        print(df)
    else:
        print("No data found in response or incorrect response structure.")
else:
    print(f"Error: {response.status_code}")
    print(response.text)

# Error message received:
# {
#     "code": 40002,
#     "message": "Please correct the information in invalid metric fields and try again. Invalid metric fields: ['campaign_name', 'page_content_view_events', 'ad_name', 'conversion_rate_v2', 'engagements']. ",
#     "request_id": " ",
#     "data": {}
# }
# No data found in response or incorrect response structure.


I've tried adjusting data_level parameters without success. How can I resolve this issue?
